# How to filter and loop through a nested associative object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, multidimensional-array, methods, associative-array

So I have three nested associative objects/arrays in total. Employee1 and employee2 were first made, and then employees was created in order to nest the two associative objects. Next, I created a third associative object, employee3, to nest into the employees object. What I am trying to do now is filter through the 2D array using the .filter() method to only bring up the employees that are currently working there, which is indicated in the arrays by ["isCurrent"] = true; but all I'm getting in the console window is undefined. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

```js
var employee1 = [];
employee1["id"] = 33;
employee1["name"] = "Carey Shanks";
employee1["title"] = "Knife Maker";
employee1["department"] = "fabrication";
employee1["isCurrent"] = true;

var employee2 = [];
employee2["id"] = 34;
employee2["name"] = "Giles Newman";
employee2["title"] = "Lead Sales";
employee2["department"] = "Customer Service";
employee2["isCurrent"] = true;

var employees = [];
employees[0] = [];
employees[0]["id"] = 33;
employees[0]["name"] = "Carey Shanks";
employees[0]["title"] = "Knife Maker";
employees[0]["department"] = "fabrication";
employees[0]["isCurrent"] = true;

var employee3 = [];
employee3["id"] = 35;
employee3["name"] = "Tori G.";
employee3["title"] = "Product Demonstrator";
employee3["department"] = "Marketing";
employee3["isCurrent"] = false;

//MERING THE ARRAYS
employees.push(employee2);
employees.push(employee3);

//TESTING TO SEE IF IT POPULATED
//window.console.log(employees);

var i;
var currentEmployee = function (isCurrent) {
    var isCurrentEmployee = true;
    for (i in employees) {
        if (isCurrent !== true) {
            isCurrentEmployee = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isCurrentEmployee;
};
var isCompanyEmployee = employees.filter(currentEmployee);

window.console.log(isCompanyEmployee[i]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- Arrays should only be used with numeric indicies. If you want to use arbitrary string keys, use an object instead.
- The first argument to the `filter` callback is the current item being iterated over; your

  ```
  var currentEmployee = function (isCurrent) {
  ```

  defines `isCurrent` as the first argument, but that's not the `isCurrent` property. If you wanted to immediately extract the `isCurrent` property from the object, destructure the parameter instead, and then you can just return it:

  ```
  var currentEmployee = function ({ isCurrent }) {
    return isCurrent;
  }
  ```

  Or, if you're not comfortable with destructuring, this is equivalent to

  ```
  var currentEmployee = function (employee) {
    return employee.isCurrent;
  }
  ```
- `i` has no meaning outside the `currentEmployee` function - log the filtered array instead:

  ```
  console.log(isCompanyEmployee);
  ```
- You never push `employee1` to the array.

```js
var employee1 = {};
employee1["id"] = 33;
employee1["name"] = "Carey Shanks";
employee1["title"] = "Knife Maker";
employee1["department"] = "fabrication";
employee1["isCurrent"] = true;

var employee2 = {};
employee2["id"] = 34;
employee2["name"] = "Giles Newman";
employee2["title"] = "Lead Sales";
employee2["department"] = "Customer Service";
employee2["isCurrent"] = true;

var employees = [];
employees[0] = {};
employees[0]["id"] = 33;
employees[0]["name"] = "Carey Shanks";
employees[0]["title"] = "Knife Maker";
employees[0]["department"] = "fabrication";
employees[0]["isCurrent"] = true;

var employee3 = {};
employee3["id"] = 35;
employee3["name"] = "Tori G.";
employee3["title"] = "Product Demonstrator";
employee3["department"] = "Marketing";
employee3["isCurrent"] = false;

//MERING THE ARRAYS
employees.push(employee1);
employees.push(employee2);
employees.push(employee3);

//TESTING TO SEE IF IT POPULATED
//window.console.log(employees);

var i;
var currentEmployee = function ({ isCurrent }) {
    return isCurrent;
};
var currentEmployees = employees.filter(currentEmployee);

window.console.log(currentEmployees);
```

Comment: This definitely helps, but for some reason the first row is being shown twice in the console and I only want to show it once.

Comment: You defined 4 objects with the `isCurrent` (etc) properties, so I assumed you wanted to call `.filter` on an array of those 4 objects. In your original code, your `employee1` object looks to be a duplicate of the `employees[0]` object - if you only meant to include one of them, just remove the other, and the code should still work.

Comment: That worked. I'm just beginning to understand objects vs. arrays.

Comment: So is var employee2 = {}; and var employee3 = {}; now objects? Now it looks like var employees = []; has an object within it? Is my thinking correct?